# Horizontal list not going inline / in one line

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

I'm trying to make a horizontal list where each of the `<li>`s in the list have a height of 385px and a width of 400px.

I tried making the list horizontal by using inline-block, but that doesn't seem to be working.
By which, I mean the list is still vertical. The `<li>`s are the right size, but the list is not horizontal.

How can I make this list horizontal? (Preferably without flexbox)

Here is my CSS:

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}
#slides{
    list-style:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#slides li{
    height:385px;
    width:400px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <ul id="slides">
            <div id="first">
            <li>
               1
            </li>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <li>
                2
            </li>
        </div>
        <div id="last">
            <li>
            3
            </li>
        </div>
        </ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a float:left to #slides li

```
#slides li{float:left;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about floating them.

Comment: hey why you unchecked the green tick :( @IrfanMir

Comment: oh, because the issue is still unresolved. I'm sorry I thought I commented here. It was fixed, but I added a little more styling and it went back to vertical. I am trying to get the overflow to be horizontal so that the list is horizontal and it is overflowing over the `<fieldset>`. So that it looks like this: http://cl.ly/image/3s0r0b000F2X. Any idea on how to achieve that? Here is my code / the page so far: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/setup.html

Comment: nevermind, I got that secondary issues answered in a new question and gave you the green-tick back. :-)

Comment: Sorry I just saw your messages. Gr8 to know you got your solution - @IrfanMir :)

Answer (score 4):

You are making it totally wrong, you are using `div` which are block level element, also you cannot use any other element except `li` inside `ul`, so your markup is invalid, instead do it like this

```
<ul>
   <li><div>A</div></li>
   <li><div>B</div></li>
</ul>

<style>
ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Oh, I did't know my markup was invalid. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: It was working, but when I changed the markup like you suggested, the list became vertical again. See how the overflow ( the list ) is vertical. How can I get it to be horizontal and overflow horizontally. Here is the page where it is happening: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/setup.html

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Do you mind checking my link to see why it is vertical. If you want, I can put the code in a JS Fiddle.

Comment: I am trying to get it to look like this: http://cl.ly/image/3s0r0b000F2X So the overflow happens on the x axis, not on the y.

Comment: @IrfanMir Give borders to each element when you test, you'll get why this is happening

Comment: Okay, thank you. I figured out why this is happening and fixed it.

Comment: @IrfanMir Glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `div`s and float the `li`s to the left:

HTML

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <ul id="slides">
            <li id="first">1</li>
            <li id="second">2</li>
            <li id="third">3</li>
        </ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}
#slides{
    list-style:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#slides li{
    height:385px;
    width:40px;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X6LkZ/1/

Comment: I need to keep the divs, how can I do it with the divs

Comment: to refer to the different items in the list. The first item, second item, I can't use nth-child because of support issues.

Comment: @IrfanMir ok, then put the id's to the li's (see my update). despite it works in some browsers, the usage of div between ul and li is invalid

Comment: okay, well someone suggested that I move the `<div>`s inside the `<li>`s and I am find with that, except now the list is vertical again. See how the overflow ( the list ) is vertical. How can I get it to overflow to the right / in the horizontal direction? Here is the page where this is happening: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/setup.html

Comment: change the width of `#slides li {` to `40px` and it will fit in one line. :)

Comment: also, you said 'overflow vertical' and 'overflow to the right'.. just correcting: it is 'float'. 'overflow' is another css property.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want the list items to still have the width that they have, but to overflow horizontally. So they are all on one line and there is an overflow-x not an overflow-y like there is now. As seen here, this is what it should look like: http://cl.ly/image/3s0r0b000F2X